# Will my virtual environment folder still work if i shift it from my local machine to a shared folder?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Currently, I have a Flask app waiting to be shifted to a shared drive in the company's local network. My current plan is to create a virtual environment inside a folder locally, install all the necessary dependencies like Python3, Flask, Pandas and etc. This is to ensure that my Flask app can still reference to necessary dependencies to run the app.

As I can't access my shared drive via command prompt, my plan is to create a virtual environment locally then shift it to the shared folder together with all the scripts required by my Flask app. Will the app be able to run on the shared drive in this manner?

Comment: Provided the host and the VM are running the same kind of OS, theoretically yes. You can try and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `virtualenv` hardcodes the path of the environment into some of its files in the environment it creates, and stops working if you rename it etc. So no, you'll probably have to recreate the env on the destination server.

Perhaps your app's startup script could take care of creating the env if it's missing.